# Custom attributes for angular translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing a research if I can use a non alphabetic characters for  custom translate value attributes. I walked through that doc

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement

and I was playing around here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MFxE13ioZfzH74TcarM7?p=streamer

```
var translations = {
  VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT: '{{aa}}_REQUIRES_AN_APPROVAL',
  VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT2: '{{@@}}_REQUIRES_AN_APPROVAL'
};
```

and I cant display 2nd line of translations as long as I use some symbols in angular expression e.g. {{@@}}

Does anybody know what symbols are allowed for custom attributes of angular translate? Or way to workaround this so that symbols are allowed?

I could not find any doc on that, but I am new to programming so maybe I was searching wrongly:)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337047/744534) answer, `@@` can't be an identifier.

Hence `@@` can't be part of translation texts.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!